# mysql error resource id#5

Tags: php, mysql

I have this little code snippet, but it's not really working right now. I always have the resource id#5 error. I searched in google for a few pointers but didn't found mutch to pass this issue. Here my code

```
<?php
include 'load_db.php';

$var1 = $_POST["gender_1"];
$var2 = $_POST["gender_2"];
$var3 = $_POST["age"];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT url FROM links WHERE gender ='".$var1."' AND gender1 ='".$var2."' AND age ='".$var3."'");

$result_1 = mysql_query($sql)
OR die("Error: $sql </br>".mysql_error());

echo $result_1;
?>
```

> Error: Resource id #5

Comment: Whats in "load_db.php" ?

Comment: `<?
$dbname="lp";
$dbhost="localhost";
$dbuser="root";
$dbpass="";
mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname);
?>` is in load_db.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using twice `mysql_query()`, remove `mysql_query()` from `$sql`:

```
$var1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["gender_1"]);
$var2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["gender_2"]);
$var3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["age"]);

$sql = "SELECT url FROM links WHERE gender ='".$var1."' AND gender1 ='".$var2."' AND age ='".$var3."'";
$result_1 = mysql_query($sql) OR die("Error: $sql </br>".mysql_error());
```

then loop in results:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_1)){
    print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: And you did exactly like I said?

Comment: I was too quick, the loop thing wasn't posted yet. Now it's working! Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

A few pointers:

1. Although you create 3 local variables, var1,var2,var3, you are still open to the exploits available with mysql insertion.. you should look into this.
2. your code:

> ```
> $sql = mysql_query("SELECT url FROM links WHERE gender ='".$var1."' AND gender1 ='".$var2."' AND age ='".$var3."'"); 
> $result_1 = mysql_query($sql)  OR die("Error: $sql </br>".mysql_error());
> ```

You call the sql_query twice..

change the $sql to just

```
$sql = "SELECT url FROM links WHERE gender ='".$var1."' AND gender1 ='".$var2."' AND age ='".$var3."'";
```